# Closed curve not intersecting a disc means all points in the disk have the same winding number

Tags: complex-analysis, homotopy-theory

Consider the following question

> If $w \in \mathbb{C}$, $r > 0$, and $\gamma$ is a closed curve which does not meet $D(w, r)$, show that $I(\gamma; w) = I(\gamma; z)$
> for every $z \in D(w, r)$.

First I thought that this is just an exercise of decomposing a path into bits on which the winding number stays the same by considering the "interior" of closed segments (i.e. of the loops) and mapping it to the unit disc by the Riemann Mapping theorem and dealing with that.

However, this gets ugly fast and it assumes that $\gamma$ is $C_1$. At this point in the course we have not even talked about functions that are nowhere differentiable and I am not aware how one can use homotopy to "smooth them out" as doing so will probably use the result of this question.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this question for such general curves as described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality we can assume that $w=0$, this simplifies the calculations a bit. Now fix a point $z \in D(0, r)$. We want to show that $I(\gamma, z) = I(\gamma, 0)$.

For all $\zeta $ in the image of $\gamma$ is $|\zeta| \ge r > |z|$ and therefore, using the geometric series:
$$
 \frac{1}{\zeta - z} = \frac{1}{\zeta(1 - z/\zeta)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{\zeta^{n+1}} \, .
$$
The series converges uniformly with respect to $\zeta \in \operatorname{Im}(\gamma)$ since
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left|\frac{z^n}{\zeta^{n+1}} \right|
\le \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|z|^n}{r^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{r-|z|}
$$
so that the order of integration and summation can be interchanged:
$$
 I(\gamma, z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{d\zeta}{\zeta - z} 
= \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(z^n \int_\gamma\frac{d\zeta}{\zeta^{n+1}} \right) \, .
$$
But for $n \ge 1$ is
$$\int_\gamma\frac{d\zeta}{\zeta^{n+1}} = 0$$
because the integrand has an antiderivative in $\Bbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}$. It follows that
$$
I(\gamma, z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{d\zeta}{\zeta} = I(\gamma, 0)
$$
and this finishes the proof.

---

On a more general level one can argue that the function
$$
 z \mapsto I(\gamma, z)
$$
is continuous and integer-valued in $\Bbb C \setminus \operatorname{Im}(\gamma)$, which implies that $I(\gamma, z)$ is *constant* on every connected component of $\Bbb C \setminus \operatorname{Im}(\gamma)$. In particular, since $D(w, r)$ is a connected subset of the complement of the image, $I(\gamma, z)$ is constant on $D(w, r)$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Just to clarify, the more general answer takes care of curves that are not necessarily \(C_1\), correct?

Comment: @MathsWizzard: What kind of curves do you have in mind? Both approaches should work whenever $\int_\gamma d\zeta/(\zeta - z)$ is defined.

Comment: The issue is that in my course we have only defined the integral along $C_1$ curves. I was thinking that we need to prove this result for any closed curve. I think that your second proof should work regardless of the nature (as long as it is continuous) using the the definition of the winding number involving $ (\theta(1) - \theta(0)) / 2\pi $

Comment: @MathsWizzard: Yes, if you can show that the winding number for general continuous curves is continuous and integer-valued then the second approach works.